# Why i am unable to click the notification,message,profile section

Tags: laravel, notifications, clickable

I am currently doing laravel project and I have downloaded the Ace admin template. I have mentioned my problem details in the image. User manager, notification, messages and profile section are not clickable. What might be the problem?

The thing is I want to log out the admin section from the dashboard. I have successfully done the login section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Mrq.png)

Comment: may be you are missing some js files.press f12 and check your error

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
dashboard:1922 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard:1922)
    at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2) 
i am getting error like this in console

Comment: are you using cdn or custom js files?

Comment: I am using custom js file.

Comment: then your path is wrong.that is why it's giving 404 error

Answer (score 0):

> I think you forget to give url to the usermanager and notification profile

In your image I see like this, your url should be look something like this **newportal.test/admin/dashboard/usermanager**. Instead of **newportal.test/admin/dashboard/#** because you are appending # in your url, So click function wont work in your case.

[image]

**Solution**

Give a anchor tag to your notification and usermanager

```
<a href="newportal.test/admin/dashboard/usermanager" >User manger</a>
```